# Resolve merge conflict automatically by renaming file with script

Tags: python, bash, git

When the automatic merge fails like this:

```sh
$ git pull --rebase=false origin master --verbose

info: detecting host provider for 'https://git.somewhere.doh/'...
From https://git.somewhere.doh/frankhommers/gitdrive-test
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
Auto-merging readme.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in readme.md
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I would like to run a bash or python (or any other language) script that performs following steps:

- Rename the incoming file automatically to `<filename>_conflicted_yyyymmddThhmmss.<ext>`
- Tell git that the merge conflict is resolved (Don't know if this is actually necessary)
- And then push it to origin again

But I don't know where to start writing that script, there must be some git CLI guru's that can help out? :)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to tell git the conflict is resolved. Otherwise you won't be able to commit.

Comment: Remember to add a step to commit before pushing back to origin.

Comment: I am not an expert but you might find the [git documentation on merge strategies](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies) helpful.

Comment: You can certainly do that, but merge conflicts exist because the merge cannot be automated. This seems to just kick the problem down the road. Instead, this might be a process problem. Most processes avoid making local commits to master; instead work exclusively in branches and merge them into master. Could you describe your process and why you need this script?

Comment: @Schwern I know, it is a deliberate choice to push the conflicts down the road ;)
I have a few tools that I want to let stuff auto push and commit to git on two devices. 
I want to keep them in sync through git so I have versioning. I know there are other tools, but I need git ;-)

Comment: @frankhommers There are two versions of the conflicting file, the local one and the one being pulled from the remote. Which version do you want to retain and which do you want to rename? I'll again suggest that you ask a question about the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of asking how to implement your solution.

Comment: @Schwern Well I want to rename the incoming file as I have mentioned. I think I have asked what I want to do, it is exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: @frankhommers The one being pulled then, ok. This won't keep them in sync, pushing back partial merges will just mix up the two code bases. You're going to have merge conflict ping-pong.

Comment: If you insist on doing this unwise thing, then I urge you to at least also commit the renamed conflicting files.  That way it is visible in the origin repo that there is additional work required, and information about just what work that is.

Answer (score 1):

I'll get to how to do this, but first you have to listen to why this is probably a bad idea.

Merge conflicts exist because the merge cannot be automated. If you try to automate it, you will wind up with partially merged code where the conflicting files are overwritten. That partially merged broken code is pushed back to the repo. Then when another repo does the same thing they'll push their partially merged broken code and overwrite the same file with their version.

To illustrate...

| repoA | repoB |
| --- | --- |
|  | changes files including a.code |
|  | pushes |
| pulls |  |
| changes files including a.code |  |
| pushes |  |
|  | changes files including a.code |
|  | pulls |
|  | a.code is in conflict |
|  | moves a.code to a_conflict_.code |
|  | restores a.code with its own |
|  | pushes partially merged probably broken code |
| changes files including a.code |  |
| pulls |  |
| a.code is in conflict, even worse now |  |
| moves a.code to a_conflict_.code |  |
| restores a.code with its own |  |
| pushes partially merged probably broken code |  |
|  | changes files including a.code |
|  | pulls |
|  | a.code is in conflict, even worse now |
|  | moves a.code to a_conflict_.code |
|  | restores a.code with its own |
|  | pushes partially merged probably broken code |

And back and forth and back and forth, each overwriting the other, each working with and pushing a partially merged broken code base, each making the conflict worse.

I expect this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and it would be better to ask about what problem you're trying to solve with this. If you have two devices changing the same file, perhaps they should write to different files.

---

A merge is just a commit with two parents. Normally Git makes the edits, stages, and does the commit for you. When there is a conflict, Git will stage as much as it can and leave the rest of its incomplete edits unstaged.

You tell Git the merge conflict is resolved by staging the conflicting files. Then it can commit them.

Your tool would have these steps...

1. `git pull`
2. Identify the conflicted files: `git diff --name-only`
3. `mv` the conflicted files.
4. Restore the local version of the files: `git restore --ours <filenames>`
5. `git add .`
6. `git merge --continue`

Comment: I couldn't have upvoted any answer that did not include some variation on the "don't do this" part.